# Which way of object instance creation is the fastest in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following 3 different ways of creating an object instance.

I was wondering which of one of these is faster, takes less memory and why?

```
//Option 1        
export interface Animal1 {
    name: string;
    color: string;
    isHungry: boolean;
}
let animal: Animal1 = {
    name: 'cat',
    color: 'brown',
    isHungry: true
};

//Option 2   
export class Animal2 {
    name: string;
    color: string;
    isHungry: boolean;
}
let animal2: Animal2 = new Animal2();
animal2.name = 'cat';
animal2.color = 'brown';
animal2.isHungry = true;
     
//Option 3   
export class Animal3 {
    constructor(public name:string, public color:string, public isHungry:boolean) {}
}
let animal3 = new Animal3('cat', 'brown', true);
```

As of coding style and maintenance I prefer option 1 with builder classes in unit testing. Option 3 is the least favourite as it's:

- Difficult to create an object easily, you have to set all properties
- Difficult to maintain, every time a new property is added you need to update every single instance creation
- Error prone, when the number of properties with the same type is high, e.g string, string, string. You may set the wrong property.

Is there any performance/memory difference between these three?

Comment: I don't have an answer to the performance question, but option 3 can be written more concisely using [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties): `constructor(public name: string, public color: string, public isHungry: boolean) {}`.

Comment: The first way should be the fastest as it does not invoke a function call. Remember that TypeScript is transcompiled to JavaScript and `new` actually calls a function in which the function context `this` is set to a new empty object.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen true, it's better way of doing it. I copy and paste the option 2 and forgot to change it.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I updated it, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## It is not possible to say, in a general sense, which is “fastest”.

Object instance creation is highly optimized in JavaScript engines. The speed will be affected by the surrounding code, the frequency with which it is run, the runtime version and many other factors.

I’m sorry this is not the answer you wanted.

In terms of memory, you can simply count the objects created by each approach - but unless you are writing a highly optimized piece of JavaScript (unlikely), this will be moot.

Typically your choice of pattern for object creation should be driven not by performance, but by non-functional requirements like the style of code agreed by the team, maintainability and API shape.

Of course, algorithms written in TS or JS **can** still be analysed for time and space complexity in the usual way.

Comment: I agree, I'm trying to come up with a coding style with my team. We mostly use interface however a new developer has joined us recently and he prefers option 3 because then he can create a new object quicker in unit tests (although we normally create builder classes to help creating new objects in tests) . So I wonder if there are any performance gain here ...

Comment: yes and no - we have complex objects. In the tests we need to create objects to test

Comment: I think that thinking about this from a performance point of view is ridiculous. But why don't you just measure it for your usecase? You'll see how many hundreds of thousands of objects you can create in a second and then decide whether performance really matters here.

Comment: Empirical measurement is valid, but tough to do accurately due to (unknown to you) engine optimisation strategies.

Answer (score 3):

The same as in JavaScript. There might be the little difference in object creation times, but the noticeable impact on overall performance of the code which uses these types. These options are not equal.

The reason is "hidden classes" JIT optimization and things JIT can do with the monomorphic code. If object members are always initialized in the same order, JIT can assign the same "hidden class" to all of the type instances and then use this information to access class members using memory offset instead of the expensive hash table lookup. When you iterate through the collection of objects having the same hidden class (or repeatedly call the function with arguments having the same hidden classes) JIT can recognize the monomorphic code and compile the specialized version of the function with excessive type checks omitted, dynamically inline method calls, and do some other magic which makes modern JS VM so fast.

So, in general, the monomorphic code is faster than the polymorphic one, and the order of properties initialization is being used by JIT to determine the "internal object type".

https://draft.li/blog/2016/12/22/javascript-engines-hidden-classes/

https://richardartoul.github.io/jekyll/update/2015/04/26/hidden-classes.html

The easiest and safest way to enable these optimizations is to use the class and make sure that all class members are always initialized in the same order in its constructor *which is an option 3 from your example.* Option 2 is the worst as there's no guarantee that the "hidden class" will be the same for the different class instances, and JIT won't consider them having the same type.

The last but not least. There's nothing obvious about JS JIT performance. Not only JIT engines use slightly different (yet very sophisticated) optimization strategies, but they evolve at a time which makes the majority of articles about JIT internals obsolete in quite a short period of time. However, "hidden classes" or similar optimizations allowing JIT to take advantage of the monomorphic code are fundamental for the JS JIT performance.

Anyway, don't guess about performance and don't believe in seemingly obvious things others say. Measure it.

Comment: Modern engines are far too complex to state that option 3 is the fastest “in most cases”.

Comment: Option 3 is a guaranteed way to enable hidden classes, thus it is quite safe to state that it's the fastest option in most cases specifically because "modern engines are too complex".

Comment: There is nothing “guaranteed” about it. You’ll likely get a hidden class in all three cases.

Comment: You might. But there's nothing guaranteed about initialization order in other cases. Not to mention that it's legal not to initialize some members in option 2, and you'll lose the same hidden class. I think it should be quite obvious.

Comment: With option 3 though, the similar init order and props are obviously guaranteed, and the user of the data structure shouldn't bother. Which is very far from "nothing".

Comment: Personally, I wouldn’t use the term “guaranteed” as liberally as you. As you point out in your answer, engines continually evolve. The question asked about object _creation_ performance which is very difficult to second-guess without knowing engine internals, hence my answer.

Comment: For property lookups, based on publicly available (and likely outdated) information on how V8 hidden classes work, and per your observation, you will get different different hidden classes if users choose to initialise object own-properties in different orders - but you will still get hidden classes and a memory-offset-based property lookup (albeit using different “class transitions”). So the performance will likely be roughly the same. In real life, of course, other factors will play into a real-world performance - but to try to guess the outcome would be to understand the engines.

Comment: ...hence my answer: no one option can be said to be “the fastest”.

Comment: Ben, when all class members are being initialized in the class constructor in the same order and when you're properly using TypeScript type system to cut off improper member assignments, it's guaranteed that V8 and other popular browsers JIT engines will employ "hidden class" or similar optimization. It's not even close to "guaranteed" with all other options.

Comment: "but you will still get hidden classes and a memory-offset-based property lookup (albeit using different “class transitions”). So the performance will likely be roughly the same." - the trick is to have all type instances to share the same hidden class, Ben. Not just "every instance to have some hidden class". So, performance won't be the same. Of course, I seen your answer. Between us, I believe it is the wrong answer. That's exactly why I gave another one.

Comment: “when all class members are being initialized in the class constructor in the same order and when you're properly using TypeScript type system to cut off improper member assignments, it's guaranteed that V8 and other popular browsers JIT engines will employ "hidden class" or similar optimization” Please show me where in the spec this guarantee exists.

Comment: Not everything can be found "in the spec", such as general JIT compilation techniques and principles. Yet they exist, and if you choose to disregard them you probably shouldn't answer questions about performance, because JIT effect on performance is dramatic.

Comment: It's enough to say that an evidence shows that all popular JS desktop VMs will generally respond well to "all fields initialized in the same order in constructor" in the variety of contexts. The reasons for that are described in the link a gave (and you can find more if you want to). I don't see the point in further discussion about the meaning of the word "guaranteed". It should be quite clear what I mean.

Comment: I updated my answer to make the point clear. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: Your hidden class discussion will be useful to future readers. However, I’m afraid I still think your opening statement is too broad: “In most cases, an Option 3 is the fastest overall option (if you will count all operations, not just an object creation time)”, and this prevents me from upvoting your answer.

Comment: Check it out now.

Comment: I’d like to avoid developers thinking option 3 is simply faster. Arguments can be made option 1 is faster to instantiate (although w/out testing/reading engine source/guide this is a guess). For prop lookup, option 3 doesn’t guarantee instantiation order will be the same every time (although I concede is more likely). Any prop lookup perf gain might be outweighed by other code characteristics dictated by use of option 3, & in most applications any gain will be undetectable. Finally, the constructor dependency injection pattern brings with it a bunch of negative non-functional characteristics.

Comment: It's not just about property lookup. It's more about letting the JIT know that it's dealing with the monomorphic code. I guess you can achieve the same effect without classes if you wrap object creation in the factory function instead of the constructor (which is technically almost the same factory function is JS). But I do not share this modern belief that OO or constructors per se is something that should be avoided in JS. Moreover, having experience with Erlang and Haskell I'm pretty sure that JS is an awful functional language. But that's the topic of the different discussion.